# Which formula do I use to integrate $ \int {\sqrt{x^2 + 81} \over 2} \,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am having trouble with a question really need help please.

$$
\int {\sqrt{x^2 + 81} \over 2} \,dx
$$

I thought about taking the square root off and turning the question into $\frac 12 \int (x^2 +81)^{1/2}\, dx$ but then wondered if I could use the quotient rule.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such thing as a "quotient rule" for integration.  What other techniques do you know?  If this is HW for a course, what section are you currently studying?  There is a particular technical method that works, based on the fact that "$x^2 + a^2$" shows up inside a radical.

Answer (score 10):

Hint: Put $x = 9 \tan{t}$, then $x^{2}+81 = 81(\tan^{2}(t)+1) = 81 \cdot \sec^{2}(t)$.

Answer (score 4):

$$ \int \sqrt{x^2+81} dx $$

Integration by parts formula

$$ \int u(x)v^{'}(x) dx = u(x)v(x) - \int v(x)u^{'}(x) dx$$

Therefore assume that $v^{'}(x) = 1$ in this case

Denote the integral

$$ I = \int \sqrt{x^2+81} dx$$

$$
\begin{align*}

 I &= x \sqrt{x^2+81} - \int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+81}} dx\\
  &= x \sqrt{x^2+81} -  \int \frac{x^2+81-81}{\sqrt{x^2+81}} dx\\
  &= x \sqrt{x^2+81} - I + 81 \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+81}} dx
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore

$$ 2I = x \sqrt{x^2+81} +81  \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+81}} dx$$

the rest you should do it yourself.

I was told that we are not supposed to give complete solution for 
homework questions.

IMPROVED EXPLANATION: (BY REQUEST)

$u(x) = \sqrt{x^2+81}$ and

$v(x) = x$, therefore $v^{'}(x) = 1$

$$ u^{'}(x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+81\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \times 2x = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+81}}$$

$$
\begin{align*}
\int \sqrt{x^2+81} dx  &= \int u(x) v^{'}(x) \\
  &= u(x)v(x) - \int u^{'}(x) v(x) dx\\
  &= x \sqrt{x^2+81} -  \int \frac{x^2+81-81}{\sqrt{x^2+81}} dx\\
  &= x \sqrt{x^2+81} - \int \sqrt{x^2+81} \hspace{3pt} dx +  \int \frac{81}{\sqrt{x^2+81}} dx\\

\end{align*}
$$

Comment: In your final expression, the variable $x$ appears outside the integral, without any proper definition there. You should change this notation.

Comment: Check http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%28x%5E2%2B81%29

Answer (score 3):

Added. **Euler substitution**

- The [Euler substitution](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Euler_substitutions) 
  $$\begin{equation*}
  \sqrt{x^{2}+81}=t-x\Leftrightarrow x=\frac{1}{2}\frac{t^{2}-81}{t},
  dx=\frac{1}{2}\frac{t^{2}+81}{t^{2}}\;\mathrm{d}t
  \end{equation*}$$
  reduces the given integral to an integral of a rational function in $t$
  $$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{1}{2}\int \sqrt{x^{2}+81}dx &=&\frac{1}{2}\int \left( t-\frac{1}{2}\frac{t^{2}-81}{t}\right)
  \cdot \frac{1}{2}\frac{t^{2}+81}{t^{2}}dt \\
  &=&\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{6561+162t^{2}+t^{4}}{4t^{3}}dt=\frac{1}{16}t^{2}-\frac{6561}{
  16t^{2}}+\frac{81}{4}\ln t.
  \end{eqnarray*}$$

Added 2. **Hyperbolic substitution**

- The hyperbolic substitution $$\begin{equation*}
  x=9\sinh t\Leftrightarrow t=\operatorname{arcsinh}\frac{x}{9},dx=9\cosh tdt,\end{equation*}$$ gives $$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{1}{2}\int \sqrt{x^{2}+81}dx &=&\frac{1}{2}\int 9\sqrt{81\sinh ^{2}t+81}
  \cosh t\,dt \\
  &=&\frac{81}{2}\int \cosh ^{2}t\,dt \\
  &=&\frac{81}{2}\int \left( \frac{e^{2t}}{4}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{e^{-2t}}{4}
  \right) \,dt \\
  &=&\frac{81}{2}\left( \frac{1}{8}e^{2t}+\frac{1}{2}t-\frac{1}{8}
  e^{-2t}\right).
  \end{eqnarray*}$$ Since $t=\operatorname{arcsinh}\frac{x}{9}=\ln \left( \frac{x}{9}+\frac{1}{9}\sqrt{x^{2}+81}\right) $, we obtain $$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \frac{1}{2}\int \sqrt{x^{2}+81}dx&=&\frac{81}{2}\left( \frac{1}{8}e^{2\operatorname{arcsinh}\frac{x}{9}}+\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{arcsinh}\frac{x}{9}-\frac{1}{8}e^{-2\operatorname{arcsinh}\frac{x}{9}}\right) 
  \\
  &=&\frac{81}{16}\left( \frac{1}{9}x+\frac{1}{9}\sqrt{x^{2}+81}\right) ^{2}+
  \frac{81}{4}\ln \left( \frac{1}{9}x+\frac{1}{9}\sqrt{x^{2}+81}\right)  \\
  &&-\frac{81}{16}\left( \frac{1}{9}x+\frac{1}{9}\sqrt{x^{2}+81}\right) ^{-2}
  \\
  &=&\frac{81}{4}\ln \left( \frac{1}{9}x+\frac{1}{9}\sqrt{x^{2}+81}\right) +\frac{1}{4}x\sqrt{x^{2}+81}+\text{Constant}.
  \end{eqnarray*}$$

---

There is a general method for integrating a function of the form $P(x)/\sqrt{ax^{2}+bx+c}$ I have already posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/40332/752).

*If* $P(x)$ *is a polynomial of degree* $n\geq 2$, *we can find a polynomial* $Q(x)
$ *of degree* $n-1$ *and a constant* $C$ *such that*$^1$

$$\int \frac{P(x)}{\sqrt{ax^{2}+bx+c}}\;\mathrm{d}x=Q(x)\sqrt{ax^{2}+bx+c}+\int \frac{C}{\sqrt{ax^{2}+bx+c}}\;\mathrm{d}x.$$

The given integral is $1/2$ of
$$
\begin{equation*}
I(x):=\int \sqrt{x^{2}+81}dx=\int \frac{x^{2}+81}{\sqrt{x^{2}+81}}\mathrm{d}x=Q(x)
\sqrt{x^{2}+81}+\int \frac{C}{\sqrt{x^{2}+81}}\mathrm{d}x,
\end{equation*}$$
with $Q(x)=Ax+B$. To find the constants $A$ and $B$ differentiate both sides
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x^{2}+81}{\sqrt{x^{2}+81}} &=&A\sqrt{x^{2}+81}+\frac{2x\cdot \left(
Ax+B\right) }{2\sqrt{x^{2}+81}}+\frac{C}{\sqrt{x^{2}+81}} \\
&=&\frac{2Ax^{2}+Bx+81A+C}{\sqrt{x^{2}+81}}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
and equate the coefficients in the numerators
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
2A &=&1\Leftrightarrow A=\frac{1}{2} \\
B &=&0 \\
81A+C &=&81\Leftrightarrow C=\frac{81}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Consequently
$$
\begin{equation*}
I(x)=\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{x^{2}+81}+\frac{81}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+81}}\mathrm{d}x.\end{equation*}$$
Note: This result is essentially the same as Kirthi Raman's.
The integral on the right can be easily evaluated using the substitution $x=9u$, because then becomes a direct integral 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+81}}dx &=&\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^{2}+1}}\mathrm{d}u \\
&=&\operatorname{arcsinh} u=\operatorname{arcsinh}\frac{x}{9}+\text{Constant}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

To write it in terms of the natural logarithmic use the [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Inverse_functions_as_logarithms) 
$$\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{arcsinh}u=\ln \left( u+\sqrt{u^{2}+1}\right) 
\end{equation*}.$$

$^1$ Described in *Cálculo Integral em* $\mathbb{R}$ by M. Olga Baptista.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method I see here is to replace x by something else. We know that $a^2+x^2 = x^2+81 = 9^2+x^2$ therefore we can put $x = 9\tan(\theta)$ and get

$dx = 9\sec^2\theta d\theta$

Therefore $$1/2 \int \sqrt{9^2+9^2\tan^2(\theta)} 9\sec^2 \theta d\theta =$$

$$27/2 \int \sqrt{1+\tan^2(\theta)} \sec^2 \theta d\theta =$$

$$27/2 \int  \sec^3 \theta d\theta $$

Comment: you don't need to delete your own answer if someone answers at the same time as you.

Comment: @HarryStern: It is usually a good idea to try to reduce noise, though.

Comment: okay! thanks. PS sec^3 is a lot of fun to integrate

Comment: I am just new here, but I wonder how people vote here because this elaborates first answer (by Chandrasekhar), but that got 11 votes and this has 0 (I am voting this one)- Weird voting system

Answer (score 1):

There exists a simple formula for the integrals of the type $\int{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}} dx$ i.e. $$\int{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}} dx=\space\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\arctan{\frac{x}{a}}+ C$$ You can prove this by putting $x= a\tan\theta$, differantiating both sides to get $dx=a \ \sec^2\theta \space d\theta$, and evaluating the simple integral that follows. Using this formula, your problem is given by
$$\int {\sqrt{x^2 + 81} \over 2} \,dx= \int \sqrt{x^2 + 9^2} \,dx=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{x^2 + 9^2}+\frac{81}{2} \arctan{\frac{x}{9}+C}$$
Hope this helps.